# Initialize array elements at run time

Tags: c, arrays, runtime

I am new to C, and I am trying to initialize array elements at run time, according to user input (so if the user inputs 4, then array[0]=4).

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
#define maxValue 100

int array[MAX];
int n;
int main(void){
   scanf("%d", n); //asks for array value
   if (n <= maxValue)
   {
      array[0] = n;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, but triggers an access violation.
What's wrong?

Comment: You should be passing the address of n to `scanf()`.

Comment: Please try to find the flags that allow the compiler you use to warn you about such problems.  With GCC, a sensible option to use is `-Wall` to catch a large variety of such errors.  Other compilers will probably need other options.

Comment: I forgot about the address of operator. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing &n to scanf.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

As Jonathan pointed out, this is easily caught by a compiler warning. For gcc you can use `-Wall` which will show you:

```
warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
  'int' [-Wformat]
scanf("%d", n); //asks for array value
       ~~   ^
```

Comment: I totally forgot about the address of operator! Such a noob mistake. Code works now. Thanks for your help.